# Can I take money from my 403b to buy a home at 65 years old without penalty

Tags: united-states, home-ownership, withdrawal, 403b

I will be 65 years old in July. My mother died and left my siblings and me her home. Can I use the money in my 403b to buy my siblings out?

Comment: without penalty?

Comment: What qualifies as a penalty?  There would likely be taxes due and possible fees for selling the investments to take out the cash that I don't know if that would fit within what you'd call a penalty.

Comment: I ask my 14 yr old "If we call puppy's tail a leg, how many legs does he have?" Her answer? 4. "You can it whatever you want, it's still a tail." There's tax due, and there's the penalty for pre-59-1/2 withdrawal he won't pay. Most pages of our crazy tax code will never confuse penalty with tax and we shouldn't either. Finance, Math, and English, I am going to be pedantic and say words have meaning for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

At your age, there is no penalty, just tax due. Depending what the house is worth, and how much needs to come out of the 403(b), it might be advised to divide the withdrawals over 2 or 3 years. 
I strongly recommend you use one of the free online tax software packages and see the tax impact of the withdrawal.